# Meteor - Handling insertion of duplicate _id

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm in the process of adding tag support to my app and plan to have a separate collection for my tags and generate my own _id value. My plan is to form the _id from the user inputted tag (e.g. user inputs "computer science" would have an _id of "computer-science"). My reasoning for forming my own _id is that the _id enforces uniqueness, so inserts without a duplicate would occur straight away and those with a duplicate would generate an error that could be handled. If this is not a good approach for performance, let me know an alternative approach.

Assuming the above is a good approach...

Is it recommended to perform an insert to a collection without checking to see if a document with the same _id already exits - allowing the duplicate error to occur in cases of a duplicate? If so, how should the error be handled? In the collection.insert callback function?

Any example code that shows a recommended pattern would be very helpful.

I guess the recommendation of whether to check or not to check for a duplicate before insertion may depend on the frequency of expected duplicates over time.

Answer (score 0):

Meteor automatically adds _id  values to each collection, those _ids are all distinct. You should not provide the _id field, it will be automatically added.

If you want to provide your own auto-increment id field, you could use `getNextSequence()`, as explained in the [mongo documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/).

**Edit**
Creating distinct values should not be a problem, you should be able to:

```
CollectionName._ensureIndex('tag-id', {unique: 1, sparse: 1});
CollectionName.insert(data, function(err, id) {
  //err should contain any duplication errors.
});
```

Or, you could create an addTag method that would simply check to see if the tag already exists before adding it.

Comment: I don't have any problems with ensuring uniqueness, but more about performance of doing the check of existence in all the cases of the tag not existing in the collection. Is it best practice to perform the check of existence even though you can possibly handle the error when there is a duplicate? I edited my question to try to provide some clarity.

Comment: If there is a duplicate insertion, collection.insert should throw an error. (I updated my answer, see example.) You can handle the duplication error within the insert callback. Handling the duplication error in the callback should be less expensive then running another query to perform a check for the id's existence.